# How can I delete user from asyncstorage and the database while minimizing total queries?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native

When I delete a user manually from my database, I want to also delete him from `asyncstorage` as otherwise the user is still logged in.

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to add a middleware to each api request and then check the user id stored in `asyncstorage` against the id stored in the db.

That however would mean that I query the database on every request more than I would otherwise.

Is there a way to achieve this while minimizing database queries?